# Ul/LI with image above centred text, in a single UL?

Tags: css, html-lists

I was wondering if it's possible to achieve an effect as shown in my mock up, with a single ul as opposed to a ul for the image and a ul for text, to to have an image and text shown below in a single ul, using css?
Something like this

```
 <ul>
  <li><img src=""/><p>text</p></li>
  <li><img src=""/><p>text</p></li>
 </ul>
```

Any help would be great,

Cheers

Here's the mock up:

[image: mock up]

Comment: what you want to do???

Comment: can you please upload what you tried?

Comment: The answer is, yes you can do that with a single UL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completely doable. Each `<li>` gets an `<img>` and `<p>` tags, and then `text-align:center;` on the `<ul>`.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100.png>
        <p>Here's a caption</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100.png>
        <p>And another caption</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100.png>
        <p>One more caption</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul{
    text-align: center;
}
li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/verybradthings/pen/ByQvdj?editors=110)